# zip file to unzip and rename files and zip back

Tags: zip

I need help in creating a bat file that enables me to the following automatically.

I have a ZIp file by name abc.zip and it contains files-test.txt,dec.drl,tes.txt .What i need is that first it needs to unzip the file and then rename file names to parent zip file like abc.txt,abc.drl,abc.txt. 
and then finally it need to zip it back.

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Sekhar

Comment: well, well, well, my friend, then have you asked the google? Also, see [here](http://ss64.com/nt)

Comment: Hello,I got this but i dont know where to provide the input path for zip...md textfiles
for %%f in (*.zip) do (
winzip -v "%%f"
move *.txt textfiles\%%~nf.txt
)
xcopy textfiles\*.txt originalfolder
rd textfiles /s /q

Comment: tried to do the above using `cmd` under Windows XP and I couldn't get it to work myself, so I'm not sure what to tell ya.

Answer (score 0):

OP, below is the code that should accomplish what you're trying to do.  Copy and paste the code block into your favorite editor (notepad-mod, notepad++, programmer notepad, etc.) and save it as a batch file.  I have included comment for each steps but if you still have a problem understanding certain command please refer to the link posted by @Alexej Magura for more information (especially variable expansion in the loop).

Note: I used 7zip instead of winzip.  You can replace 7zip command with appropriate winzip command.  This script was tested on Windows 7.

```
:: # creating test files
echo hello>files-test.txt
echo world>dec.drl
echo !!!!!>test.txt

:: # showing you the directory listing
dir
pause

:: # creating test zip file (abc.zip)
7z a -tzip abc files-test.txt
7z a -tzip abc dec.drl
7z a -tzip abc test.txt

:: # showing you the directory listing
dir
:: # showing you the content inside the zip file
7z l abc.zip
pause
:: # Finished prepping your scenario (abc.zip with 3 files inside)



:: # Core Logic
:: # Looping through all the zips
for %%c in (*.zip) do (
    :: # Make a temporary folder with the same name as zip to house the zip content
    if not exist %%~nc md %%~nc
    :: # Extracting zip content into the temporary folder
    7z e -o%%~nc %%c
    if exist %%~nc (
        :: # Jump into the temporary folder
        pushd %%~nc
        if exist *.* (
            :: Loop through all the files found in the temporary folder and prefix it with the zip's name
            for %%i in (*.*) do (
                ren %%i %%~nc.%%i
            )
            :: # Zip all the files with the zip prefix with orginal zip name but with a number 2 (abc2.zip)
            if exist %%~nc.* (
                7z a -tzip %%~nc2 %%~nc.*
            )
            :: # Move the new zip back out of the tempory folder
            if exist %%~nc2.zip move %%~nc2.zip ..
        )
        :: # Jump out of the temporary folder
        popd
        :: # Showing you the directory listing
        dir
        :: # Showing you the content inside the new zip
        7z l %%~nc2.zip
        :: # Remove the temporary folder (Clean up)
        rd /s/q %%~nc
    )
)
```